# Javascript prototype syntax - variable name starting with underscore

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am following an online tutorial and coming across a bit of javascript code which I'm having a tough time understanding.  There is a function called Note() defined in javascript.  Below is the code for adding getters and setters in the the prototype section.  I don't understand why the variable _id has underscore in front of it?  What's the purpose of the underscore and when is it used?

```
Note.prototype = {
    get id() {
        if (!("_id" in this))
            this._id = 0;
        return this._id;
    },

    set id(x) {
        this._id = x;
    },

    get text() {
        return this.editField.innerHTML;
    },

    set text(x) {
        this.editField.innerHTML = x;
    }
```

Comment: It's just a convention indicating the variable is private.

Comment: How come when I take the underscore out it doesn't work?

Comment: `id` is defined by its getter and setter, you can't use the same name for a property storing a value.

Comment: So if I define id in the class and set it to null.  can I take the underscore off of the getter and setter?

Comment: I tried defining the variable the class and took the underscore out.  The code doesn't work properly without the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I narrowed down the issues and I reposted this question.

It turns out that 'name' and '_name' are two completely separate variables.  If we use 'name' in the setters and getters it results in an infinite recursive call of the function which is why it doesn't work properly.

You can find the repost of this question with additional information here.

[Javascript getters and setters - recursion issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809960/javascript-getters-and-setters-recursion-issue)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Thank you @fracz.  I will update this shortly.

Comment: Thank you @Gary.  I will update this shortly.

Comment: You could simply have edited the question since you didn't have answers yet. I've duped your post now since the question has morphed into the repost.