# JavaScript getters and setters - recursion issue

Tags: javascript, recursion, getter-setter

What is the significance of the '_' character in the setters and getters of JavaScript?

For example, I have the following code which works fine.

```
var user = {
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    },
    set name(value) {
        this._name = value;
    }
};

var me = user;
me.name = "Rob";

alert(me.name);
```

But if I remove the underscore so my code will look like the following, then my code won't work and I get a an error in the browser console stating "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded."

```
var user = {
    get name() {
        return this.name;
    },
    set name(value) {
        this.name = value;
    }
};

var me = user;
me.name = "Rob";

alert(me.name);

</script>
```

What does the "_" do in this situation?

Comment: the `_name` (*with* underscore) is *private* to your `user` object but the `name` (*without* underscore) is public and changeable from the outside scope. so basically, you call `name` from outside, which then calls itself again and hence it becomes recursive.

Comment: there are no private/public properties in js, it's just a name conflict. you need a state var separate from your access property for getters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's quite simple. In your second example, the `get`, calls itself.

Since you reference the property `me.name`, JavaScript needs to `get` that property. When this happens, the getter is triggered. Using your second example, JavaScript calls the getter, but the getter is then told to do the exact same thing: get the property that it is meant to handle. The function always calls itself, making it infinitely recursive.

However, in the first example, the property that is being retrieved in the getter is not the same as the one that originally triggered the getter. The value being retreived by the getter is somewhat of a storage component to avoid the problem of recursion mentioned above. The two properties have no actual connection between them even though they have similar names.

The same idea applies to the setter.

Comment: Question - is this a convention in js that any property being manipulated using getter/setter should be added with a underscore ?

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha It’s sometimes used for private fields, which those are. Anibe Agamah’s answer talks about that more.

Comment: Let’s say I have a property `this.name` and i am trying to access it in `get name` using `this.name` then recursion happens, that’s understandable. But by making just one change inside `get name` I.e. by using `this._name` it works fine. So, It seems like js has **added something internally** to identify the property with `_` with the normal property name. That is something I am still not sure about.

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha By using `_name` instead of `name` you are using an entirely different variable. You could use any other variable name except `name`. If you use `name`, JavaScript needs to call it’s getter, which is current function, which causes infinite recursion. It’s the same as this: `function getname() {return getname()}`. If you use `_name` which does not have a getter, you just get the value.

Comment: But by using `this._name` I am getting the value for this.name. (Inside `get name()` function)

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha You would be getting the value for `_name`. There is no value for `name`. It’s basically a function without parentheses. In this example you are just storing the value for `name` in `_name`. There is no connection between the variables.

Comment: Thanks for your patience man you’re awesome. I realised that I was making some silly mistake.

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha No problem. I’m glad you figured it out.

Comment: The error occurs for both the getter and setter in the post (the setter invokes itself when setting a  value). For readership, the setter (`me.name = "Bob"`)  in the example is actually the line which causes the recursion.

Answer (score 5):

Its naming convention used to identify private variables or properties. The `_` doesn't have any sign of particular significance to JavaScript.

From the Airbnb JavaScript [style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript):

> Use a leading underscore _ when naming private properties.

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#22.4